# Newline and whitespace inside function bar being removed in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a very long formula that is near impossible to read and would like to add newlines and tabs to it so the next person who has to change it, doesn't have to spend forever trying to read it.

Ive already given up on using tab but after I stop editing the formula it removes basically of the formatting including the newlines. Is there anyway to stop this from happening?

Comment: my issue is not how to add new lines. the lines I add with Alt + Enter disappear after I stop editing the formula

Answer (score 0):

I Figured it out. I wont use my formatting but after a few changes it formatted it.

[This isnt allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmMuR.jpg)

[This is allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9raqW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets formula bar doesn't save changes when only a break line is inserted. In order to keep the change, add something else like

```
=A1+B1   
+0
```

Then remove the `+0`